# Is naming an app similar to another app legal?

Tags: legal, publishing

I just finished my first ever app after 1 month of programming it and I'm ready to put it on the app store/google play. I searched the stores to see if the name i wanted to name my app was still available. Say i wanted to name my app "example App". I found an app named "exampleApp" but the name "example App" was still available. Could I still legally put my app name as "example App" without worrying about getting sued or having to get my app name changed? The game play and graphics are entirely different. Thanks.

P.S. That app also has over 1,000,000 downloads so if I could still name my app "example app" would that be a bad idea and make it harder for people to find my app? Or would it make my app more popular by someone accidentally finding it in the search?

Comment: Having a unique name will make your app stand out more. (Legal issues aside ...)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice, not about developing a game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether they have registered the name as a [trademark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark). The liability with respect to similarity ("My Product" vs "MieProduct") in specific instances is a matter for lawyers to advise and courts to decide.

> That app also has over 1,000,000 downloads so if I could still name my app "example app" would that be a bad idea and make it harder for people to find my app? Or would it make my app more popular by someone accidentally finding it in the search?

This is why trademark law exists - to prevent brand confusion. If someone actually buys your app thinking it's the other app they heard about then you've harmed the other app's business, or vice versa.

It's also kind of rude to use a name someone has already published, particularly when publishing has an associated advertising cost. While you might have *thought* of using the name first, they may have invested money (or time) into that name already. Thus, you would effectively steal the benefits of their advertising money as well.

Comment: how must one tell if the name is trademarked? I wont name my app "example app" regardless be like you said it is rude. And btw the app is called TapDefense if you need to see it. and thanks for the response.

Comment: You can use http://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/ to search the US trademark database, but even that may not include everything, since the a trademark may be filed but no decision has been made. If you file for a trademark they are supposed to check for existing marks for you.

Comment: I say "supposed to" because ultimately any argument over ownership has many, many common law factors that would be decided in civil court with the help of IP lawyers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to file/register a trademark for it to be considered "trademarked". If the name has a "TM" after it, then it is trademarked, if it has an "r" in a circle then it is a registered trademark. Regardless, these both mean "finders keepers" with regards to titles and the first person (exampleApp) has somewhat of a legal upper-hand.

People might buy your app if you have a more clever name anyway.
I suggest you start brainstorming :)